# Lines disappeared after removing the last character of a string using Python

Tags: python, json, file, character

I would like to remove the last comma in imperfect.json and replace it with a square bracket.

imperfect.json (there is a blank line at the end of the file)

```
...
{
"Q1":"1242",
"Q1":"14336",
"Q2":"13210",
"Q3":"11855",
"Q4":"11496",
"SubmitID":103, "Worksheet":5, "UserID":75},
{
"Q2":"13210",
"Q2":"11110",
"SubmitID":104, "Worksheet":5, "UserID":75},
```

But when I ran the following code, it removed 68 lines of my original file and successfully appended the closing square bracket at the end.

```
f2 = open('imperfect.json')

tempstr = f2.read()
tempstr = tempstr[:-1]
tempstr = tempstr + '}]'

with open('useful_input.json', 'w') as perfect_file:
   perfect_file.writelines(tempstr)
```

what I got in useful_input.json

```
...
{
"Q1":"1629",
"Q2":"1950",
"Q3":"0116",
"Q4":"616",
"SubmitID":91, "Worksheet":4, "UserID":72},
{
"Q4":"0616",
"Q3":"0117",
"SubmitID":92, "Worksheet":4, "UserID":72},
{
"Q1":"14336",
"Q2":"11110"}]
```

How can I remove only the last character of imperfect.json?

Comment: `writelines` is intended for a sequence of strings.  Have you tried `write` instead?

Comment: I just tried, it gave the same result

Comment: On my Ubuntu 14.04 system, with Python 2 I get a correct result (ending with `UserID":75},}]`) - what OS and Python version are you using?

Comment: Your code should work as expected. Are you sure you are reading the right `imperfect.json` file?  Remember `open('imperfect.json')` will look for the file in your current working directory.

Comment: I use Mac OS, Python 3.5 and PyCharm

Comment: The output has different submitId, worksheet, and userid values to the input --- @AnthonyKong's idea look like a good one to check on.

Answer (score 0):

To remove only the last character from a string, just use `string[:-1]`,
but if you have trailing white spaces, you will need to use the `strip` method to remove them.

> The chars argument is a string specifying the set of characters to be removed. If omitted or `None`, the chars argument defaults to removing whitespace. The chars argument is not a suffix; rather, `all combinations of its values are stripped`

Example using `rstrip` to remove trailing white spaces:

```
tempstr = tempstr.rstrip()[:-1]
```

Getting the same result by calling `rstrip` twice:

```
tempstr = tempstr.rstrip().rstrip(',')
```

Answer (score 0):

It'd be better if you use

```
tempstr = tempstr.rstrip(',\n')
```

This is a bit less error-prone than

```
tempstr = tempstr[:-1]
```

The latter variant strips *any* char, while the former strips only the comma or line-break and leaves any other chars alone.